# Switching Panels on button event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a row of panels on my WindowsForm which have two buttons on each, Move Up and Move down. I want it so that when the user clicks down it switches the current panel with the panel beneath it essentially taking its place. (swapping them over). I have 10 instances of the same panel so something simple like the below isnt working because all the panels are called DataPanel. Any help is appreciated.

```
 private void MoveDownEnabled_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point temp = DataPanel.location;
        DataPanel.Location = Panel2.Location;
        Panel2.Location = temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend storing the `Panel` in a collection, for a start. This will make the code for accessing the next panel, very clean.

```
ArrayList panels = new ArrayList();
panels.add(panel);
panels.add(panel2);
panels.add(panel3);
```

ANd also keep a value, `index`, to show where in the list you're up to.

```
private int index = 0; // Set it to a default value.
```

Then ammend your button click code:

```
 private void MoveDownEnabled_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Panel Current = panels.get(index);
    if(index < panels.Count)
    {
        // Grab the next item.
        Panel Next = panels.get(++ index);
        // And this part is up to you!
    }
 }
```

You seem to have the right idea with how you're swapping them around, so I think now I've set this up for you, you can work the rest out for yourself.

Comment: Use List<T> instead of ArrayList.

Comment: Do i not implement a List on the movedownenabled_click?

Comment: If you re-implement the list on every click, that defeats the point of using a collection. Can you use it on form load?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use your variable name to differentiate controls at runtime, use their properties or their instances. In this case, you can use the Panel's `Name` property to differentiate, or its `Tag` property which can hold an object type. Also, I recommend storing the Panels in a collection such as a List so that they can be iterated and accessed easily.

For example (as a general idea)

```
//won't get nested panels but sounds like you don't need that
var listOfPanels = this.Controls.OfType<Panel>().ToList();

//access the panel you want by name
Panel pnl = listOfPanels.Where(x => x.Name == "panelName").FirstOrDefault();
```

In your case, your Panel events will be send the panel as the `sender` in your event handler.

```
private void MoveDownEnabled_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel selectedPanel = sender as Panel;

    if(selectedPanel != null)
    {
       Point temp = DataPanel.location;
       DataPanel.Location = selectedPanel.Location;
       selectedPanel.Location = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple swap method should do:

> ```
>     public void SwapPanels(System.Windows.Forms.Panel pnl1, System.Windows.Forms.Panel pnl2)
>     {
>         var localtion1 = pnl1.Location;
>         var location2 = pnl2.Location;
>         pnl2.Location = localtion1;
>         pnl1.Location = location2;
>     }
> ```

if you want to swap any two panels, just call this method to swap them. if you have many panels, just store them in a list or so and swap them freely.